# PHP - replace values of array with another array

Tags: php, arrays, replace

Is there a way i can replace the values of one array with the values of another which has identical keys?

```
$arr1 = Array
        (
            [key1] => var1
            [key2] => var2
        )
$arr2 = Array
        (
            [key1] => var3
            [key2] => var4
        )
```

I want to change $arr1's values to the ones in $arr2 im doing this about 10 times, and i can do it line by line, but im wondering if there's a simpler way.
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check php's [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function.

```
$arr1 = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
```

Comment: wont that just create double the keys?
EDIT: it worked, thanks!

Comment: It depends on what you're using for keys in your array. String keys will take the 2nd's value, numeric keys append.

Answer (score 10):

If the keys in array 1 and 2 are identical:

```
$arr1 = $arr2;
```

If all keys of array 2 are guaranteed to be in array 1 (array 2 is a subset of array 1):

```
$arr1 = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
```

If some keys of array 2 are not in array 1 and you want only the keys that are in array 1 to be replaced (array 2 is not a subset of array 1, and you only want to merge the intersecting part):

```
$arr1 = array_merge($arr1, array_intersect_key($arr2, $arr1));
```

Comment: this way would also work (the first one) but the next step would replace $arr2 with values from $arr3, so i think array_merge would work better

Comment: @Diesal If `$arr1 = $arr2` actually works for you, you don't really want to *merge* arrays as much as *replace a variable* wholesale. Maybe with some more code we could recommend a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: well in the end it goes back to rows in MYSQL, im actually replacing the values of one rows columns with the next row. i haven't fully written it up yet. so thats all i can give you atm

Answer (score 2):

If you need to preserve an order of the array, use [array_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php):

```
    $a = array( 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2,  'c' => 3  );
    $b = array(           'b' => 20, 'c' => 30 );

    $r = array_replace($a, $b)

    // $r = array( 'a' => 1, 'b' => 20, 'c' => 30 );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Editing Notes:
>   This answer previously suggested using `array_combine` as a way of doing this. However, as several people have pointed out, that's *not* the correct way of solving this problem. This answer has been edited to be more relevant to actually solving the problem.

---

To replace the values of one array with the values of another array you can use the PHP [`array_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) method. This assumes associative arrays with identical keys.

The PHP documentation explains `array_replace` like this:

> array_replace() replaces the values of array1 with values having the same keys in each of the following arrays. If a key from the first array exists in the second array, its value will be replaced by the value from the second array. If the key exists in the second array, and not the first, it will be created in the first array. If a key only exists in the first array, it will be left as is. If several arrays are passed for replacement, they will be processed in order, the later arrays overwriting the previous values.

---

Also, this post: https://softonsofa.com/php-array_merge-vs-array_replace-vs-plus-aka-union/ includes a handy graphic which helps to explain the difference between array_merge, array_replace, and the array union operator (`+`). Give the post the read if you desire, I've included the image below for reference:

[image: from: https://softonsofa.com/php-array_merge-vs-array_replace-vs-plus-aka-union/]

Comment: array_merge() as NullUserException posted is probably the better way to go. Either method would work if the keys are the same.

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. It would create `array('var1' => 'var3', 'var2' => 'var4')`

Comment: @Felix - Thanks for catching that - I stand corrected. This is definitely the wrong way to do what the OP wants. This is the correct way of doing this with array_combine, `array_combine(array_flip($arr1), $arr2);`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the replace function.

```
$arr1 = array_replace($arr1, $arr2);
```

or better of if you want to deal with multi-dimensional array, use recursive replace.

```
$arr1 = array_replace_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
```

For details check these links [array_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php), [array_replace_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php)