# Merge same column in two different array

Tags: php

I am trying to Merge same column in two different array,
Array2 is the part of Array1, for some updation on PartyName column I am fetching that column from main array1 using array_column then applying some modification to array2 then want to merge it again.
like

**Array1:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [StorePartyId] => 10462791
            [StoreId] => 4
            [PartyName] => AMAR MEDICO
            [PartyCode] => 6840
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [StorePartyId] => 10463839
            [StoreId] => 4
            [PartyName] => NEW SAVE MEDICINE SHOPEE
            [PartyCode] => 8236
        )
)
```

**Array2:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PartyName] => AMAR MEDICO_updated
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [PartyName] => NEW SAVE MEDICINE SHOPEE_updated
        )
)
```

I can programmatically merge this two array by looping each other.
but looking for some inbuilt function of php array.
I tried array_merge function but it does not resolve this.

**FinalArray**

final array should look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [StorePartyId] => 10462791
            [StoreId] => 4
            [PartyName] => AMAR MEDICO_updated
            [PartyCode] => 6840
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [StorePartyId] => 10463839
            [StoreId] => 4
            [PartyName] => NEW SAVE MEDICINE SHOPEE_updated
            [PartyCode] => 8236
        )
)
```

Comment: check this answer:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34270630/4248328   and output with your values:- https://3v4l.org/B1qHi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use array_replace_recursive to replace recursive arrays.
`array_replace_recursive($Main_array, $Replacements);`

```
$new = array_replace_recursive($arr,$arr2);
```

Returns:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["StorePartyId"]=>
    int(10462791)
    ["StoreId"]=>
    int(4)
    ["PartyName"]=>
    string(19) "AMAR MEDICO_updated"
    ["PartyCode"]=>
    int(6840)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["StorePartyId"]=>
    int(10463839)
    ["StoreId"]=>
    int(4)
    ["PartyName"]=>
    string(32) "NEW SAVE MEDICINE SHOPEE_updated"
    ["PartyCode"]=>
    int(8236)
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/fjTlq

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume

Your current data is stored in `$array1`, updated field data is stored in `$array2`

```
foreach($array1 as $key=>&$arr){
    if(isset($array2[$key])){
        $arr=array_merge($arr,$array2[$key]);
    }
}
```

Here I have used `&` sign for pass reference of the element.
Now `$array1` is final array with updated value

Answer (score -1):

I use array_merge and it works as you wish

```
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green");
$a2=array("c"=>"blue","b"=>"yellow");
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
```

Result :

```
Array ( [a] => red [b] => yellow [c] => blue )
```

Comment: Won't work in this case https://3v4l.org/qblkZ